# Gradually change background color based on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, colors

I have a scrollview that when it is scrolled down the background changes color.

I know I could use UIView animations to make this automatic. But I want to set a color based on the percentage of the scroll.

I want set the 0% and the 100% colors and the current color would be calculated and set on `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
 0%               50%              100%
yellow           green             blue
```

**EDIT**

How can I calculate the new color based on the scroll position?

Comment: OK, what's your question?

Comment: How can I calculate the new color based on the scroll position

Comment: What part do you need help with? Do you know how to calculate the scroll percentage? Is your question just about the color? Start by answering what color your want for 10%, 25%, 75%, etc. I'm not aware of any standard progression to go from yellow to green to blue.

Comment: I do know how to calculate the scroll percentage, my problem is how do I create a gradient between two colors **and** get the color on a specific position (percentage)

Comment: That's a question for you. As I said, what color do you want at 25%? In other words, what's between yellow and green in your case? What about 75%? What about all of the others? What colors do **you** want?

Comment: Like I told you, I want to **create a gradient between two colors**. With that gradient I should be able to get a `UIColor` for each position. When the scroll is at 25% **I just check on the gradient which color should I use**.

Comment: @NicosKaralis You didn't say _anything_ about a gradient. If that's your question, please edit the question to reflect that. Your question _never_ mentions gradients.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a solution for Swift 3.

```
// This function calculates a new color by blending the two colors.
// A percent of 0.0 gives the "from" color
// A percent of 1.0 gives the "to" color
// Any other percent gives an appropriate color in between the two
func blend(from: UIColor, to: UIColor, percent: Double) -> UIColor {
    var fR : CGFloat = 0.0
    var fG : CGFloat = 0.0
    var fB : CGFloat = 0.0
    var tR : CGFloat = 0.0
    var tG : CGFloat = 0.0
    var tB : CGFloat = 0.0

    from.getRed(&fR, green: &fG, blue: &fB, alpha: nil)
    to.getRed(&tR, green: &tG, blue: &tB, alpha: nil)

    let dR = tR - fR
    let dG = tG - fG
    let dB = tB - fB

    let rR = fR + dR * CGFloat(percent)
    let rG = fG + dG * CGFloat(percent)
    let rB = fB + dB * CGFloat(percent)

    return UIColor(red: rR, green: rG, blue: rB, alpha: 1.0)
}

// Pass in the scroll percentage to get the appropriate color    
func scrollColor(percent: Double) -> UIColor {
    var start : UIColor
    var end : UIColor
    var perc = percent
    if percent < 0.5 {
        // If the scroll percentage is 0.0..<0.5 blend between yellow and green
        start = UIColor.yellow
        end = UIColor.green
    } else {
        // If the scroll percentage is 0.5..1.0 blend between green and blue
        start = UIColor.green
        end = UIColor.blue
        perc -= 0.5
    }

    return blend(from: start, to: end, percent: perc * 2.0)
}

// In your "scrollViewDidScroll" delegate, calculate the scroll 
// percentage as a value from 0.0 to 1.0
// Then call "scrollColor"
let scrollPercentage = ... // your calculation
let scrollColor = scrollColor(percent: scrollPercentage)
```

Comment: Thank you. The `blend(from:to:percent:)` was perfect for my needs